# Segmentation fault in c++ code involving unorder_map ans stack

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack, unordered-map

```cpp
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::vector<std::string> operations(n);
  std::cin.ignore();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    getline(std::cin, operations[i]);
  }
  std::unordered_map<int, int> my_map;
  std::stack<int> my_stack;
  my_map[0] = INT_MIN;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::string query = operations[i];
    if (!query.empty()) {
      if (query[0] == '1') {
        query.erase(0, 2);
        int num_to_push = stoi(query);
        my_stack.push(num_to_push);
        int size = my_stack.size();
        if (my_map[size - 1] < num_to_push)
          my_map[size] = num_to_push;
        else
          my_map[size] = my_map[size - 1];
      }
      if (query[0] == '2') {
        my_stack.pop();
      }
      if (query[0] == '3') {
        int size = my_stack.size();
        std::cout << my_map[size] << "\n";
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the code which takes different queries for a stack and performs the action ( 1 for pushing, 2 for popping and 3 for printing the max element). I used a map to store the max value of stack using the size of stack as the key

I can't find any logical error, but the code is giving Segmentatin fault. GDB suggests that the fault is in the line

```cpp
my_stack.push(num_to_push);
```

this is the output of gdb

```cpp
Starting program: /home/oddity/aa/test < input.txt

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555558f34 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct<int, int const&> (
    this=0x7fffffffdf90, __p=0x1fc) at /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:146
146     { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000555555558f34 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct<int, int const&> (
    this=0x7fffffffdf90, __p=0x1fc) at /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:146
#1  0x0000555555558106 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::construct<int, int const&> (__a=..., __p=0x1fc) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:483
#2  0x00005555555581a2 in std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_push_back_aux<int const&> (this=0x7fffffffdf90) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/deque.tcc:496
#3  0x000055555555774b in std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back (
    this=0x7fffffffdf90, __x=@0x7fffffffdf1c: 26)
    at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:1579
#4  0x00005555555570cf in std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push
    (this=0x7fffffffdf90, __x=@0x7fffffffdf1c: 26)
    at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_stack.h:234
#5  0x00005555555566a8 in main () at /home/oddity/aa/test.cpp:25
```

the input given to the program are
`10`
1 97
2
1 20
2
1 26
1 20
2
3
1 91
3
`

I can't find the source of the error. Can you help me?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, it works for me just fine. Be sure you are not passing an empty string to `std::stoi`, in that case you would get SIGSEGV because you are not catching the exception anywhere.

Comment: The problem is that you pop an empty stack when `query[0] == '2'`. That's what my debugger confirms and it's what I expected when I just looked at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is here (see comments)

```
 if (query[0] == '1') {
    query.erase(0, 2);
    int num_to_push = stoi(query);
    my_stack.push(num_to_push);
    int size = my_stack.size();
    if (my_map[size - 1] < num_to_push)
      my_map[size] = num_to_push;
    else
      my_map[size] = my_map[size - 1];
  }
  else (query[0] == '2') { // ADDED ELSE HERE
    my_stack.pop();
  }
  else if (query[0] == '3') {  // ADDED ELSE HERE
    int size = my_stack.size();
    std::cout << my_map[size] << "\n";
  }
```

The problem is that the missing `else` and the fact that you modify query here `query.erase(0, 2)` means that two of your if clauses can be executed for the same query.

Honestly this took a couple of minutes to find with a debugger. You clearly use gdb a little but you should learn how to use it fully.